# RxJS - Diferencia entre reduce() y scan()

Tags: angular, rxjs, programación-reactiva

Estoy estudiando RxJS hace muy poco, y me surgio esta duda, no le encuentro diferencia a ambos metodos, alguien si me puede tirar una mano con la documentación. Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando usas scan(), vos aplicas la función a todos los valores sucesivamente hasta el último y los vas emitiendo. Con reduce(), solo lo aplicas al último y lo emitís ese solo.

Acá se ve mejor la diferencia:

[image: scan]

[image: reduce]